# Mails are coming under spam folder using wp_mail function in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I am using wp_mail function for sending emails for registration, i have tried with gmail, the email goes to the spam folder, i have tried similar questions answers but it is not working for me please help.

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: noreply@example.com"."\r\n";

$message = sprintf(__('Dear: %s'), $user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= sprintf(__('The email was sent automatically by '));
$message .= network_home_url('/');

$message .= __('Please visit the following link to register your email address') . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login')."\r\n";

 if ( $message && !wp_mail( $user_email, wp_specialchars_decode( $title ), nl2br($message), $headers ) )
        wp_die( __('The e-mail could not be sent.') . "<br />\n" . __('Possible reason: your host may have disabled the mail() function.') );

    return true;
```

Comment: there is no magic dont_mark_my_email_as_spam() function. if you have tried everything suggested in many places then that's all you can do

Comment: I am using pieregister plugin for registration process.

Answer (score 1):

Your email contains **phrases**, which are very common for spam emails. 
So mail servers anti-spam filters detects that and send it to the junk email folder.

The best you can do is to rework the content of your email (do not include bullshit words like `Dear...` or `Please visit the following link...`, these are at top of the anti-spam filter list, use targeted and personalized appeal, etc, the quality of the content is crucial factor).

As it has been said - there is no special function which will mark your outgoing email as not spam, if it exists - the spammers will use it like hell.

Comment: I have tried with out the long message and links but it has the same problem.

Comment: I am not sure about what happened to my php mail, is there any thing i have missed to install?